# Directly Reference Python's Standard Library

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, standard-library

So it turns out that PyQt redefines a function `hex()`, which unfortunately renders the python standard library `hex()` unusable. I'm working on a large software project and it's been set up with *imports:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

...etc

I need the standard python `hex()` function, is there any way for me to reference it? I'm thinking of a `stdlib.hex()` or something like that?

Currently my ugly workaround is:

```
pyHex = hex
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
hex = pyHex
```

and I'd really prefer to not have to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I think, this is one reason why * imports are called bad practice

Comment: I agree -- unfortunately, I'm not the only one working on this code base, and the * imports were made long before I even saw the code. So now I need a workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from __builtin__ import hex
```

Use the [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html).

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `__builtin__` has been renamed to `builtins`.

Comment: If the OP needs to use BOTH the QT hex and the Python hex, then they might want to do this instead: **from __builtin__ import hex as _hex**